# Jquery open dropdown near clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to open a absolute positioned dropdown near the clicked element that opens the dropdown. Normally you use `position:relative` and `position:absolute` but my question is a bit different.

My dropdown menu is not placed near the clicked element but instead is placed outside that div just after the `body` tag. 
So normally you would do something like this:

```
 <li class="cart dropdown-opener">
   <div class="dropdown">...html for cart..</div>
 </li>

$('.dropdown-opener').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).find('.dropdown').addClass('open');
});
```

In my case it's something along these lines:

```
 <div data-open="cart">
   <div class="dropdown">...html for cart..</div>
 </div>

 <li class="cart dropdown-opener"></li>

  $('.dropdown-opener').on('click', function(e){
    var open_this = $(this).data('dropdown');
    $(document).find("[data-open='" + open_this + "']").find('.dropdown').addClass('open'); 
  });
```

To be complete:

```
.dropdown {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    transform: translateZ(0px);
    transition-delay: 0.1s, 0.1s, 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s, 0.7s;
    transition-property: max-height, width, box-shadow;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.17, 0.32, 0.95);
    width: 0;
    z-index: 9998;
    cursor: auto;
}
.dropdown.open {
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    max-height: 500px;
    width: 650px;
}
```

What I try to do is to open that dropdown near the clicked element `cart dropdown-opener`. So that it works like when using `position:relative` and `position:absolute`.

But I have no clue where to start. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your content is *"just after the `<body>` tag"*... you're doing it wrong. In each document, there should be one `<html>` tag containing one `<head>` and one `<body>` tag, and nothing else. All content that is meant to be displayed should be contained in the `<body>` tag. Just because it works in some browsers (because they are forgiving) it doesn't mean it's valid, therefore it doesn't mean it will work in others or that it will work in yours tomorrow. Always respect the standards if you want your code to be reliable.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to make it clear what and where you are trying to display, and what's the relation between the trigger and the target, on all responsiveness intervals.